# Lombok @Builder generated class in a Gradle module not found in other module

Tags: java, gradle, lombok, multi-module

I want to add `Lombok` to a `Gradle` multi-module project, but I'm having a hard time trying to configure it. Was reading the documentation and multiple pages, however I'm not able to make it work when it relates to multi modules.

Update: upgraded to Gradle version `4.10.3`, Java 8

In IntelliJ I could make the project to recognize `@Builder` annotation in one module, and use the generated builder class in a separate module. However, when running the `gradle build` on the terminal, I'm getting:

```
/myprj/module1/src/main/java/CampaignTracker.java:143: error: cannot find symbol

CampaignBuilder campaignBuilder = Campaign.builder()
                                          ^
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class CampaignLead
```

We have the `Gradle` multi-module project that is structured like this:

```
myprj
  |- common
       |- Campaign.java
       |- build.gradle
  |- module1
       |- CampaignTracker.java
       |- build.gradle
  |- module2
       ...
  build.gradle
```

In the common module, we use `@Builder` lombok annotation in `Campaign.java` class like this:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Campaign {
   ...
}
```

Then on the separate module named `module1`, we want to use the generated builder by lombok, like this:

```
public class CampaignTracker implements Tracking {
    void buildCampaign() {
        CampaignBuilder campaignBuilder = Campaign.builder()
             .id(...)
             .name(...);
        //more stuffs
    }
}
```

In our root `build.gradle`, we have:

```
subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    tasks.withType(Test) {
        systemProperty 'user.country', 'US'
        systemProperty 'user.language', 'en'
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    }
}
```

My problem is that when gradle is compiling the second module that depends on common it is not finding the supposedly generated Lombok builder class.

Update: if I build the module independently with `gradle clean build -p commons -x test`, I see that `CampaignBuilder` is generated, but when I build the whole project it is not.

Do you have any idea why Gradle does not recognize/find the generated code by Lombok in a separate module?

Comment: I have similar setup and no issue: could you first ensure that the Gradle compiled Campain class contains the expected Builder? (open generated `/myprj/common/build/classes/java/.../Campaign.class` )

Comment: @M.Ricciuti, from the IDE it contains it, however from the command line it does not.

Comment: generally IDEA and Gradle will not generate classes into the same directory:  IDEA will output to `$proj/out/production/...` while Gradle will output to `$proj/build/classes/java/...` : did you "open" (decompile) both `Campain.class` from these two directories?  ALSO : how do you declare dependency between `common` subproject and `module1` ?

Comment: @M.Ricciuti if I build the submodule like this `gradle clean build -p commons -x test`  I can find the Builder class, but when I build the whole root project it is not generated. I'm not defining dependencies between modules using Gradle.

Comment: if `module1`depends on `commons` module (and this is the case, as you import `Campain` class in `module1`)  you need to tell Gradle to create this dependency:  in  `module1` build script , try to add `dependencies { implementation project(":commons") }`

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I think I found the issue. It looks like a misconfiguration between IntelliJ using gradle wrapper and terminal using gradle 4. IntelliJ was failing to annotation processor while gradle was not. In this, looks like IntelliJ was not generating the correct `import` class, hence the insane error. I'm double checking if I'm correct

Comment: @M.Ricciuti, I posted my answer and referenced your comments since were the most valuables to solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the Gradle build is not configured to apply Lombok- (the IDE does because it is smart enough). See the docs at [lombok-gradle](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle) ; you can either use a gradle plugin, or add to the `common` module :

```
dependencies {
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
}
```

Comment: what Gradle version are you using?  the `annotationProcessor` configuration is available since v4.6 ( see https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#convenient-declaration-of-annotation-processor-dependencies )

Comment: @M.Ricciuti using `Gradle 4.10.3`. I've updated the question because I could make the `annotationProcessor` to not trigger  `Could not find method annotationProcessor()`, however I still have the same problem where the second module is not finding the generated builder class

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer more as a comment than an answer since [Daniele](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264558/daniele)'s answer and [M.Ricciuti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6899896/m-ricciuti) helped me troubleshooting this.

There were multiple issues:

The project was using `gradle wrapper` 2.13, which does not support annotation processor. I tested using the legacy lombok plugin but could not sort out the issue. The viable solution I found was to upgrade to to latest 4.x (4.10.3).

Using this version allowed me to get rid of the legacy gradle plugin an just add Daniel's answer:

```
dependencies {
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
}
```

On the other hand, IntelliJ was configured to use the Gradle Wrapper (2.13) which does not work with `annotationProcessor` therefore the was *not* generating the `import` statements.

I mark Daniel's answer as the right answer since it also contains M. Ricciuti comment